# jQuery add class to href for target _blank

Tags: jquery, regex

I'd like to dynamically add a `class="external-link"` to all hrefs that are `target="_blank"` but excluding hrefs surrounding an `<img>` tag.

e.g.

```
<a href="#" target="_blank" >test</a> // I'd like to add a class="external_link"

<a href="#" target="_blank" ><img src="#" /></a> // Nope, no class here thanks.
```

I assume some regex would do but I can't figure out how to exclude `<img>` tags.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more general way, which can apply to any tag, is using jQuery function $obj.children() to get $obj.children().length that tells you if there is any tag or not.

```
$('a[target="_blank"]').addClass(function(){
   if($(this).children().length==0)
         return 'external_link';

})
```

Check sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/PWrU7/

Answer (score 3):

I think you can target anchor elements([element selector](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/)) with attribute `target="_blank"`([attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)) and not([.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/)) has an image as its descendant([has selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/)).

```
//dom ready handler
jQuery(function(){
    $('a[target="_blank"]').not(':has(img)').addClass('external_link')
})
```